# Windows 10 login screen not behaving like it normally does. Cannot login to account

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

When windows 10 starts up I'm greeted with the normal picturesque landscape image with clock and network icon but when I try to click or ESC to enter password the screen will flash and go right back to the picture. I've tried all key combinations CTRL+ALT+DEL, esc, enter and nothing.

So I started up a repair session by resetting during windows startup, and was able to do a startup repair but during it's process of diagnosing the problems it will just restart the system. Tried rolling back updates, still nothing. In command prompt tried all the bootrec.exe tactics \fixmbr , \fixboot (Get an access denied), \rebuildbcd (finds no installations of windows).Went in and edited the registry to auto sign in with admin account and nothing still, just the landscape screen. All these fixes I also tried with a USB boot recovery disk. What other avenues are available besides resetting the pc, and what part of windows mechanics is causing this to happen?

Comment: has this computer had a blue screen recently, or has it been shut down incorrectly (power outage,...)?

Comment: Funny you should say that, I booted hirens boot cd and was going to start checking for malware/virus, but was immediately halted with a blue screen "your pc ran into a problem...." with a QRCode, something I probably would see from a Windows 10 error. Right now I'm in the process of memory testing.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of attempting to repair this windows problem, I finally just reset the PC. Although this is technically not an answer to the problem of the corrupted logon, it was my only solution to getting back to using the computer.
This is the list of further attempts to fix the problem along with the fixes I tried that I listed in my original question and Swisstone's suggestion. A malware/virus scan with no results and a memTestx86 scan and a Windows memory Diagnostic test with no errors, Hirens hard drive tools to find hard drive problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the following file, it may be corrupted, for example if the system was improperly shut down:

`c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\caches\cversions.3.db` (you can back up the file before deleting it, but Windows should be able to re-create this by himself).
That's a cache, but its exact purpose is still unclear. However if this file gets corrupted, it will lead to the exact symptoms you are describing.

Comment: For me, removing that .db file, did not change the behavior of logon. I've tested the memory and am now in the process of malware and virus detection and removal. To be honest so far there hasn't been any errors or infection and am willing to bet there won't be any.